# how is tcpip connections managed in systemd

Tags: linux, networking, systemd

so im learning about UNIX form this book and it says init starts inetd which is the super server that listens to all network requests but in my system `/sbin/init` is symbolic link to `/lib/systemd/systemd` and there are no files like `/etc/inted.conf` in my system so what is used instead of inted and where do i add my network programs as daemons instead of `/etc/inted.conf`

Answer (score 0):

The [systemd](https://systemd.io) suite of tools is designed to handle management of all sorts of daemons, including boot/shutdown of the system. The handling of transient daemons (one shot services, start a copy for each incoming request) are just one aspect of the whole. Check out systemd's documentation, `systemd(1)` and `systemd.socket(5)` in particular.

If you have `rsync` installed, take a look at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/rsyncd.service` and `/usr/lib/systemd/system/rsyncd.socket` (or similarly named files for other services).